# jQuery Mobile Panel not closed when clicked nearer the panel

Tags: android, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, panel

I am having a little problem with a panel in my jQuery Mobile application. Everything works fine except the functionality of **Dismiss Panel on clicking outside**.

See the screenshot below which explains my issue.

[image]

Notice the red line I have made. If I click on right side of that line when my panel is open, it works fine. But if I click on left of that line then panel is not being closed.

Here is the html part.

```
<div data-role="panel" id="sidebar-menu-monthly" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-dismissible="true" data-theme="a" >
    <ul>
        <li> </li>
        <li> </li>
        <li> </li>
        <li> </li>
        <li> </li>
        <li> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried setting `data-display="push"`, too. That didn't work either.

This is the stylesheet part:

```
/* wrap on wide viewports once open */
@media (min-width:55em){
    .ui-responsive-panel.ui-page-panel-open .ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-display-push.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-position-left,
    .ui-responsive-panel.ui-page-panel-open .ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-display-reveal.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-position-left,
    .ui-responsive-panel.ui-page-panel-open .ui-panel-content-wrap-display-push.ui-panel-content-wrap-position-left,
    .ui-responsive-panel.ui-page-panel-open .ui-panel-content-wrap-display-reveal.ui-panel-content-wrap-position-left {
        margin-right: 17em;
    }
    .ui-responsive-panel.ui-page-panel-open .ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-display-push.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-position-right,
    .ui-responsive-panel.ui-page-panel-open .ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-display-reveal.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-position-right,
    .ui-responsive-panel.ui-page-panel-open .ui-panel-content-wrap-display-push.ui-panel-content-wrap-position-right,
    .ui-responsive-panel.ui-page-panel-open .ui-panel-content-wrap-display-reveal.ui-panel-content-wrap-position-right {
        margin-left: 17em;
    }
    .ui-responsive-panel.ui-page-panel-open .ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-display-push,
    .ui-responsive-panel.ui-page-panel-open .ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-display-reveal {
        width: auto;    
    }
    .ui-responsive-panel .ui-panel-dismiss-display-push {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15233617/1777090) answer, but it didn't help me. I also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311143/jquery-mobile-panel-not-animating-or-closing#comment25107115_17311143) fiddle. But it doesn't give me any idea about what changes I need to make in stylesheet.

I also tried changing `@media (min-width:55em)` to `@media (min-width:35em)`, which didn't help either.

It would be great if someone could help with stylesheet part.

P.S: I have already checked in browser that the div of Panel is not taking more width than it actually looks. So it is not the problem.

Comment: on which device/browser are you getting this problem? I couldn't reproduce it on chrome.

Comment: I am getting the error in chrome. And Samsung galaxy tab 2, Huawei ascend y 300 and all other devices on which client tested. Are you sure I haven't made any minor mistake in stylesheet? @Omar

Comment: I'm still trying to figure it out. I used chrome desktop and narrow screen. if you could post your complete code, at least page and panel, along with CSS. Also, make sure you haven't overridden .ui-page elsewhere.

Comment: Ok.. Please let me know if you figure it out. I am also trying by myself, but didn't get any success so far :( @Omar

Comment: Please post some code with jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

This css (from default jqm css - *jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css*) was creating issue

```css
.ui-panel-dismiss-open
{
  left: 17em;
}
```

So it was being dismissed in right most areas only. I had to override the css in my css file to:

```css
.ui-panel-dismiss-open
{
   left: 13em !important;
}
```

And now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was having issue with my responsive panel being closed when clicked in the right portion of it, I had to overwrite the dismiss area using the code, suggested above, except it is more useful to have it in %, so that it will work on any browser

```css
left: 80% !important;
```